# Google AdMob ads are not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, interstitial, admob

I tried to integrate GoogleAdMob - Interstitial for one of my application.
here its showing.

```
interstitial:didFailToReceiveAdWithError: Request Error: No ad to show.
Ad wasn't ready
```

At AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [GADMobileAds configureWithApplicationID:@"AppID Value"];

    return YES;

}
```

At ViewController

```
    static NSString *const GADAdUnitID = @"ADUnitId Value";
    #pragma mark - googleAdsMobile
    - (GADInterstitial *)createAndLoadInterstitial {

        GADInterstitial *interstitial =
        [[GADInterstitial alloc] initWithAdUnitID:GADAdUnitID];
        interstitial.delegate = self;
        GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
        request.testDevices = @[ @"some value"];
        [interstitial loadRequest:request];
        return interstitial;
    }

/// Tells the delegate an ad request succeeded.
- (void)interstitialDidReceiveAd:(GADInterstitial *)ad {
    NSLog(@"interstitialDidReceiveAd");
}

/// Tells the delegate an ad request failed.
- (void)interstitial:(GADInterstitial *)ad
didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error {
    NSLog(@"interstitial:didFailToReceiveAdWithError: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

/// Tells the delegate that an interstitial will be presented.
- (void)interstitialWillPresentScreen:(GADInterstitial *)ad {
    NSLog(@"interstitialWillPresentScreen");
}

/// Tells the delegate the interstitial is to be animated off the screen.
- (void)interstitialWillDismissScreen:(GADInterstitial *)ad {
    NSLog(@"interstitialWillDismissScreen");
}

/// Tells the delegate the interstitial had been animated off the screen.
- (void)interstitialDidDismissScreen:(GADInterstitial *)ad {
    NSLog(@"interstitialDidDismissScreen");
    self.interstitial = [self createAndLoadInterstitial];

}

/// Tells the delegate that a user click will open another app
/// (such as the App Store), backgrounding the current app.
- (void)interstitialWillLeaveApplication:(GADInterstitial *)ad {
    NSLog(@"interstitialWillLeaveApplication");
}
```

No ads showing on application.

Do I need to pay for subscription to googleAdMob for showing ads?

[image]

After link with firebase the Admob google i got above Ads.  but I do not see real Ads yet.  I was confused what I missed to get the application into run real ads on iPhone device.

Once the interstitial test ad from AdMob show prompt the below message.

```
 _userSettingsForUser mobile: {
    filterBlacklist =     (
    );
    filterWhitelist =     (
    );
    restrictWeb = 1;
    useContentFilter = 0;
    useContentFilterOverrides = 0;
    whitelistEnabled = 0;
}
```

I am expecting a real Ad here.

Answer (score 0):

Google suggests to either use a test device or use a sample ad unit ID.

Does it work if you remove the line for setting the test device and use this test ad unit ID, that I have from Google‘s website?

```
ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/4411468910
```

Answer (score 0):

To get real ads from Google you have to register on Google's website and make an account. Then you have to register your app in the dashboard and are able to create placements for interstitials or banners or whatever you like to. When you have created those, you get ad unit IDs for real traffic and real revenues. From then on you can observe the revenues for each placement in the Google dashboard.

Have you registered on this site?

https://www.google.com/admob/?utm_source=google%20developers&utm_medium=et&utm_campaign=googledevproductsadmob&utm_content=ads

Comment: Yes I register on google admob.  That is why I got app ID, and adunitId and googleservice-info.plist file which added into project too

Comment: Did you try to remove the line of code that says `request.testDevices = @[ @"some value"];`?

Comment: Yes I did remove the request.testSevices

Comment: Okay, then the only thing I can think about is that you need more ad requests to get the ad unit started. I worked with many ad network SDKs and some need either time to make the ad unit work at all or they need enough requests for a new ad unit to be "worthy" enough to be payed for. I even spammed ad requests sometimes and it worked after some time.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has this problem check that in your AdMob page -> apps - your app - appSettings, your app is linked with the app store. I had forgot to link mine and it was the problem for me.